# How to check if a property was assigned with 'DateTime.Now' with reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to compare two complex objects. My idea was to write a function that iterates over all properties of the object and the sub-objects and write a combination of the property name, the data type and the value in a string. The function returns the hash of this string.

So if the function returns the same hash for two objects the objects are equal. The function is fine. The problem is, that some properties are assigned with DateTime.Now.

```
tProduct.Timestamp = DataTime.Now;
tProduct.CreatedAt = DataTime.Now;
```

So if I call my function the string that is created slightly differs in those values.

Example:

```
//both objects are equal
var complexObject1 = Generate();
var complexObject2 = Generate();

var hash1 = GetHash(complexObject1); // uses string **xxx25.11.2021 15:11:51xxx** to hash
var hash2 = GetHash(complexObject2); // uses string **xxx25.11.2021 15:11:56xxx** to hash
```

I want to ignore those values in my function and I think I need reflection for this. The logic I want to implement is: If a property gets the value via DataTime.Now I will ignore it.

Comment: "How to check if a property was assigned with 'DateTime.Now' with reflection?" **you can't** - because you have no way of knowing if a value came from `DateTime.Now` or somewhere else.

Comment: "I need to compare two complex objects" - there are already countless well-regarded libraries for doing this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects/  - don't waste your time reinventing the wheel

Comment: Also time will move on as your application executes, so "now" will be always changing.

Comment: The proper thing to do would seem to be to always ignore `Timestamp` and `CreatedAt`, then. At runtime nobody (including the compiler) can tell what `Generate` is doing. While it is *technically* possible to decompile `Generate` and see if maybe it assigns things using `DateTime.Now`, this is 1) absurdly complicated and 2) absurdly fragile, so don't go that way.

Comment: "sub-objects" - I know you _really mean_ to say distinct objects referenced by member properties of your root objects in your object-graph, but "sub-objects" _can_ refer to first-class complex-types which share object-identity with their owner, but C#/.NET does not support that.

Comment: "if the function returns the same hash for two objects the objects are equal." - "I'll take _fallacies that greenhorn programmers believe about hash-codes_ for $100, Alex"

Comment: Thanks for all the replys! I will take a look at the library mentioned by @Dia.

Comment: Thanks for the explantion @Jeroen Mostert. I will try your approach to just ignore these properties. My problem with this was, that everytime the code gets changed and somewhere a property gets assigned with DataTime.Now this property needs to get ignored aswell overwise my function won't work anymore.

Comment: You can try checking by comparing with some *tolerance*: if difference between property value and `DateTime.Now` is smaller than `tolerance`  then we consider equality

Comment: The idea with the tolerance is good. I will use it aswell.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, the `DateTime` object is used for getting the current date and time from the computer.

So you don't have the possibility to compare the two values which is getting from the `DateTime.Now`

But you have the possibility in terms of speaking about the `packages`. In `NuGet`, we have numerous package to compare the values.

For eg you can use the `ObjectComparer` Package to compare the objects.By typing the below command in the `Package Manager` you can install the ObjectComparer.

```
Install-Package ObjectsComparer -Version 1.4.1
```

Comment: This is really two long comments, and not a real answer to the OP's problem. Perhaps you could show why "you don't have the possibility to compare the two values which is getting from the `DateTime.Now`"? And perhaps you could show how to use the `ObjectComparer` package to answer the question?